# Control the appearance of a form based on user interaction

Tags: forms, ms-access, conditional-statements, ms-access-2013

I have a requirement to build a form that can be used to submit two types of requests, but the data that must be collected is slightly different for each type.  That is, I have regular orders and special requests that are fulfilled with the same form.
Currently, the form contains a drop down for "Stock Items" or "Special Requests", and if Stock Items is selected, then another field, "ItemName" (which is a control list), is used to select which Stock Item is getting reordered.  The control list is important to minimize variations of spelling for items that are regularly stocked (for ease of reporting).
Special requests on the other hand must be approved by a manager, must be associated with the original request ID from another form, and there is no way to predict the ItemName, so the ItemName field must become a free text field.  So, the flow would be as follows: if "Special Requests" is selected, the ItemName field need to be cleared of the control list to allow freestyle typing, a checkbox needs to appear with the label "Manager approved?" and finally a field for entering the associated special request ID must appear, which will probably also be controlled.
Basically, I need to be able to control the flow of the form, depending on selections made.

Here's what I've done: I've gone into design view of the form, highlighted the field ItemName, and changed it from a combo box to text box confirming that I can toggle between two formats. I've then selected Conditional Formatting from Format tab, but, the available options don't allow me to evaluate the contents of another field
I have no experience with VBA programming...Can this be done without VBA code?

Comment: Re: "Can I do this using built in functionality of MS Access?" - Can *you* do this? That's impossible for us to answer. Can it be done? Yes. So what you need to do now is *try something*, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19776600/edit) your question to indicate the thing(s) you've tried, and ask a *more specific question*.

Comment: OK, I can do better job on that. edited.

Comment: anyone care to look at question?  I've found info on how to base one combo box on another combo box here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/basing-one-combo-box-on-another-HA001173058.aspx but haven't found link on making a subsequent combo box totally disappear and be replaced with a text box based on select made in former combo box.  Gord seems to think this is possible :-)

Comment: My previous statement may have been slightly misleading if by "using built in functionality of MS Access" you meant "without VBA code". It can be done using just Access (no third-party controls or add-ons necessary), but a bit of VBA will probably be required. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: no apologies needed. some assistance would be great. Any links that you can supply that would show me how to do this? It's very frustrating for you to tell me there's a solution, but not a bit of direction here. I know how to create a combo box.  I can even create two combo boxes, where one is dependent on the other.  But to have the second combo box replaced by a text field if a particular selection is made in the first, isn't something I've found any answers to. Wanna help>?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a little nudge to get you started. In your particular case you don't need to switch between a Combo Box and a Text Box based on the request type. The name "Combo Box" refers to the fact that it is a combination of a Text Box and a drop-down list.

If the `.LimitToList` property of the Combo Box is `No` then users *can* select an item from the list or they can type in some other value. If `.LimitToList` is `Yes` then they *must* select an item from the list.

So, all your form needs to do is to toggle the `.LimitToList` property of the combo box for the "Item" based on the current value of the combo box for the "Request Type". That can be accomplished by a single line of VBA code in the `After Update` event handler for the "Request Type" combo box:

```vbs
Option Explicit

Private Sub cbxRequestType_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cbxItem.LimitToList = (Me.cbxRequestType.Value = "Stock Item")
End Sub
```

As you can imagine, that same event handler (for the combo box named `cbxRequestType`) can be used to show/hide other controls on the form (e.g., the checkbox for "Manager Approved") by toggling their `.Visible` properties.